# Difference between "uncompress" and "decompress"

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between *decompress* and *uncompress*? Is there any?

Context:

> The receiving node has to **uncompress/decompress** the data.

Comment: *decompress* -- that's it.

Comment: @Kris Post that! :P

Comment: But you would say *uncompressed data* instead of *decompressed data*?

Comment: @MarcMessing *decompressed* is a **past participle** of the verb decompress. *Uncompressed* is an **adjective**.

Comment: @Alenanno: Done. And added some explanation as well. Tx.

Comment: @MarcMessing I explained the difference in my answer below.

Comment: Until the recent burgeoning of computer terms, _un-_ was hardly ever used with a verb unless the verb had a sense of fastening, attaching or enclosing. (With an adjective, including a past participle, _un-_ was used freely). _Compress_ seems to me to be marginally in this group, so _uncompress_ might have occurred, but I don't believe it did. _Uncompressed_, on the other hand, was unexceptional. Nowadays all sorts of actions that are not reversible in the real world can be reversed in software, so there are many more verbs with _un-_.

Comment: Tx @ColinFine how about some 'further reading' on the interesting aspect?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

***decompress*** — that's it.

Uncompressed = not compressed; may never have been compressed in the first place. Just plain data is uncompressed data in every sense. To specifically refer to that which has undergone the process of decompressing, we would say ***decompressed*** data. Looking at it in another way, data before being compressed is *uncompressed* — that extracted from compressed format is *decompressed* data.

---

[Edit-1] Also, per [Alenanno](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/6550/alenanno),
***decompressed*** is a past participle of the verb ***decompress***. ***Uncompressed*** is an adjective.

Comment: Also adding the reference I made above, might help (for nonnative speakers, especially). Feel free to add it to your answer. :)

Comment: @Alenanno: Done. I think OP cannot up vote.

Comment: @Kris I can though! :D +1

Comment: Seems [the Qt people](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#qUncompress) could learn a thing or two from this answer :P

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**
I would think that:
 ******uncompressed data* is data that was never altered
 ******decompressed data* is data that has been compressed, then returned to its original state by the process of *decompression*.

Decompress and uncompress seem to be used synonymously in the context of computing, although decompress seems to be used more frequently. A search on MSDN for **[uncompress*](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=uncompress*&beta=0&ac=8)** returns 731 hits, while **[decompress*](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=decompress*&beta=0&ac=3)** returns 4,450 hits.

Seaching on SO gives similar results. There are

- 22 questions tagged with **[uncompress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uncompress)**
- none tagged with uncompression,
- 651 occurrences of uncompress and
- 34 occurrences of uncompression.
  Total tag count = 22
  Total word count = 685

In contrast, there are

- 39 questions tagged with **[decompress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decompress)**
- 110 questions tagged with **[decompression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decompression)**
- 1,467 occurrences of decompress and
- 865 occurrences of decompression.
  Total tag count = 149
  Total word count = 2,332

Answer (score 0):

I landed here because of my condumdrum with 'uncompressable', which is rejected by MS Word spell check in favor of 'incompressable'. After decades in IT I'm astonished to see that all the usual resources come down on the side of 'in-'. I was using the term in the sense of 'data that cannot be usefully compressed'. Never let it be said that I'm incorrectable.

Comment: Microsoft’s ideas about how you should write are incorrigibly bad.  Turn all that crap off.

Comment: *Uncorrectable* rather, not *incorrectable*.

Answer (score 0):

From an English language perspective, I would think that uncompressed is anything that is not compressed irrespective of whether it was compressed earlier or not. From an information technology language standpoint, I have always referred to decompressed data as something that was compressed earlier and then returned to its original state.
Having said this, while reading through some SAS course notes I chanced upon the term uncompress, hence my presence on this page.

Answer (score -2):

Uncompressed data will never be "uncompressed" once it's been compressed — it'll be decompressed.

Comment: Please cite at least one reliable source.